# Why is $ \int q(\theta) \ln q(\theta) d\theta =\sum_i \int q_i(\theta_i) \ln q_i(\theta_i)d\theta_i$ if $q(\theta)=\prod_i q_i(\theta_i)$?

Tags: integration, summation, products

The context of this question is variational inference (vriational Bayes) assuming factoring posterior distributions, which is then also known as mean field theory. However the argument is purely algebraically.

Let $q(\theta)$ be a function where $\theta$ a parameter vector. Assume $$q(\theta)=\prod_{i=1}^D q_i(\theta_i),$$ where $\int q_i(\theta_i) d \theta_i=1$. Then another function is given by $$\int q(\theta) \ln q(\theta)  d\theta$$ which, under the assumption made above, apparently factorizes to

$$\sum_{i=1}^D \int q_i(\theta_i) \ln q_i(\theta_i)d\theta_i.$$

I do not understand why. I can see that

$$\prod_{i=1}^D \int q_i(\theta_i) \sum_{j=1}^D \ln q_j(\theta_j) d\theta_i$$

but I do not know how to get to the result from here.

Comment: You need to have different indices on the sum and the product or it's not clear what's going on.

Comment: @Chappers I tried to edit - better?

Comment: Yes, much. Do we know anything about $\int q_i(\theta_i)d\theta_i$?

Comment: @Chappers Yes, actually. I missed that: $\int q_i(\theta_i) d \theta_i= 1$ (it's a distribution over $\theta$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's expand the log first, so that the sum comes outside:
$$ \int q(\theta) \log{q(\theta)} \, d\theta = \int q(\theta) \sum_i \log{q_i(\theta_i)} \, d\theta = \sum_i \int q(\theta) \log{q_i(\theta_i)} \, d\theta.  $$
Now expand $q(\theta)$,
$$ \int q(\theta) \log{q_i(\theta_i)} \, d\theta = \int \left(\prod_j q_j(\theta_j) \right) \log{q_i(\theta_i)} \, d\theta. $$
Separate off the $q_i(\theta_i)$ from the product, and divide the integral up:
$$ \int \left(\prod_j q_j(\theta_j) \right) \log{q_i(\theta_i)} \, d\theta = \int \left(\prod_{j\neq i} q_j(\theta_j) \right) q_i(\theta_i) \log{q_i(\theta_i)} \, d\theta \\
= \left( \int q_i(\theta_i) \log{q_i(\theta_i)} \, d\theta_i \right) \left( \prod_{j \neq i} \int q_j(\theta_j) \, d\theta_j \right). $$
The integrals in the second bracket are all $1$, and we get the answer.

Comment: Thank you, very illuminating answer.

Comment: Didn't notice your answer when I posted. Very nice.

Answer (score 1):

It will probably suffice to see it worked out when $D = 2$:

\begin{align*}
\int q_1q_2\ln(q_1q_2) & = \int q_1q_2(\ln q_1+\ln q_2) \\
&=\int q_1q_2\ln q_1 + \int q_1q_2\ln q_2.
\end{align*}

Now the first integral is separable:
\begin{align*}
\iint q_1(\theta_1)q_2(\theta_2)\ln(q_1(\theta_1))\,d\theta_1\,d\theta_2&=
\int q_2(\theta_2)\,d\theta_2\cdot\int q_1(\theta_1)\ln(q_1(\theta_1))\,d\theta_1.
\end{align*}
And likewise the second is also separable:
\begin{align*}
\iint q_1(\theta_1)q_2(\theta_2)\ln(q_2(\theta_2))\,d\theta_1\,d\theta_2&=
\int q_1(\theta_1)\,d\theta_1\cdot\int q_2(\theta_2)\ln(q_2(\theta_2))\,d\theta_2.
\end{align*}
Since $\int q_i = 1$, you know how to take it from here.